# How can I get IOS unique ID with 16 characters max?

Tags: ios, uniqueidentifier

How can I get IOS unique ID with 16 characters max?

- [UIDevice identifierForVendor] returns 40 characters : it's too much
- The mac address cannot be returned after IOS 7

I need a unique identifier with a maximum size of 16characters like Android.

Regards

Comment: just md5 the identifierForVendor

Comment: That's the reason why Android is so much more vulnerable ;-)

Comment: simply hash the result

Comment: What level of uniqueness are you looking for here?

Comment: I want to return always the same identifier on a given device, and never return the same identifier for 2 different devices. And the size of the identifier must be max 16 chars. The md5 si not good, I could have the same value for 2 different devices.